# Why isn't SQL Agent starting after installing MS16-136 patch?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-agent

I installed MS 16-136 patch on SQL Server 2014. It updated successfully. However, since the update, SQL Agent fails to start. I've checked SQL Config. settings to ensure protocols are set up correctly and those weren't change anyway. Only thing that was done was the installation of the MS 16-136 patch. The service account is the same account that runs SQL service which is running just fine. TLS 1.1 and 1.2 are enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Had to re-enable TLS 1.0. I'll have to upgrade it to SP2 to use TLS 1.2.